# Adding String of values to the list

Tags: java, collections

Is there a way to add a string of values to the collection?LoadQueue is the classname.I am trying to create a collection and then add to the list.

```
 List<LoadQueue> list = new LinkedList<LoadQueue>();
```

Is there any way I can add like below:

```
list.add(new <LoadQueue>.AsList("DATA_QUEUE1", "QUEUE1", false));
list.add(new <LoadQueue>.AsList("DATA_QUEUE2", "QUEUE2", false));
```

I have tried using Arrays.AsList but it is not working... Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: `list.add(new <LoadQueue>.AsList` Is this Java? Please tell me it's not :\

Comment: And where is the definition of `LoadQueue`

Comment: Angular brackets are used for defining the type of collection, not instantiation of the object

Comment: `list.add(new LoadQueue("DATA_QUEUE1", "QUEUE1", false))` ??

Comment: I need to add this to the list. As the syntax says list.add(arg) what shoudl I do to create like/ add ("DATA_QUEUE1", "QUEUE1", false)

Comment: What's the constructor for LoadQueue?

Comment: Or else please tell how to add values to the list/collections if i dont want to use constructor of the class to do it. list.add(q1); list.add(q2); list.add(q3); list.add(q4); where q1 has ("DATA_QUEUE1", "QUEUE1", false);q2 has "DATA_QUEUE2", "QUEUE2", false); and so on

Comment: You can't add `String`s to a `List` of `LoadQueue`s. You can only add a `LoadQueue` or a subclass thereof. And that means you do have to use a constructor. So: how do you make a `LoadQueue`?

Comment: This OP is actually having a problem with IBM WebSphere MessageBroker. Maybe let him rephrase the question. I deleted my answer below when he told me that his problem occurs in a JavaComputeNode and that a `java.lang.InstantiationException` is being thrown. Maybe he should post the entire StackTrace here and be more explicit about the context of his problem.

Comment: What does class LoadQueue look like?

Comment: I have updated the code to be as public final String getQueueName1() {  return QueueName;}public final String getQueueName2()  { return QueueName2; } public final Boolean getAvail() {  return Avail;  }   and the setters are public final void setQueueName1(String aQueueName1)
 {QueueName1 = aQueueName1; }public final void setQueueName2(String aQueueName2) {QueueName2 =aQueueName2; } and public final void setAvail(Boolean avail){ Avail = avail; }Can you please help me to create a list?

Answer (score 0):

Create a List

But first.....I just want to confirm if this is how your LoadQueue class is...

```
class LoadQueue
{
///I dont know why this would be called Queue but you could have a queue as a datamember and add and remove data to this queue...LikeThis
//Queue q;
String msg;
String queuename;
Boolean t;

LoadQueue(String x,String y, Boolean z)
{
//q=new LinkedList<Object>; 
msg=x;
queuename=y;
t=z;
} 
}
```

Now ......

```
list.add(new LoadQueue("DATA_QUEUE1", "QUEUE1", false));
```

====================================================================

Or may be what you want is this:

```
List list=new ArrayList<Object>();
LoadQueue q=new LoadQueue("DATA_QUEUE1", "QUEUE1", false);
list.add(q.msg);
list.add(q.queuename);
list.add(q.t);
```

Comment: Doesn't `Class` have to be minor case? ==> `class` in java

Comment: It's not even pretty printed, and then it is invalid syntax.

Comment: @mwhs yes my class is pretty much the same.

Comment: I have updated the code to be as public final String getQueueName1() { return QueueName;}public final String getQueueName2() { return QueueName2; } public final Boolean getAvail() { return Avail; } and the setters are public final void setQueueName1(String aQueueName1) {QueueName1 = aQueueName1; }public final void setQueueName2(String aQueueName2) {QueueName2 =aQueueName2; } and public final void setAvail(Boolean avail){ Avail = avail; }Can you please help me to create a list?....

Comment: So there is no way to create a collection without using a coonstructor?